# InvalidSObjectFault while querying object using Tooling API

Tags: tooling-api

I am trying to get the Sobject Name by prefix of Id using below query in my JAVA code:

```
        QueryResult queryResultsAttach = conn 
            .query("Select Id,QualifiedApiName,KeyPrefix from EntityDefinition where KeyPrefix = '001' limit 1 ");
    SObject[] entityDefinition = queryResultsAttach.getRecords();
    Object apiName = entityDefinition[0].getField("QualifiedApiName");
    System.out.println("entityDefinition "+apiName);
```

This is throwing an error -

> Exception in thread "main" [InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE'
>    exceptionMessage='sObject type 'EntityDefinition' is not supported.'
>   ]
>    row='-1'
>    column='-1'
>   ]
>   ]

I ran the query in dev console using the same credentials and the query returned a record. Even hardcoded the id in query in my java program but still getting this error. Any ideas what could be missing?

Comment: Have you checked the API version. It is supported after version 32.

Comment: Yes.. it says Salesforce.com Tooling API version 40.0

Comment: Though the Tooling API WSDL said v41.0,  my service endpoint had a different version. Changed to 41.0 and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double or triple check your API version. The response you are getting is exactly what you get with [EntityDefiniton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) when you use API v31.0 or earlier.

SOAP Tooling API query to https://na87.salesforce.com/services/Soap/T/31.0/00D300000000001

**Request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader><urn:sessionId>00D30000000023456!AQ0AQIoLpcG6nREALSESSIONIDh9tFHVRr0iM3Q2iej8UZvlDNjKN</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:query>
         <urn:queryString>Select Id,QualifiedApiName,KeyPrefix from EntityDefinition where KeyPrefix = '001' limit 1</urn:queryString>
      </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>sf:INVALID_TYPE</faultcode>
         <faultstring>INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'EntityDefinition' is not supported.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:InvalidSObjectFault xsi:type="sf:InvalidSObjectFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_TYPE</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>sObject type 'EntityDefinition' is not supported.</sf:exceptionMessage>
               <sf:row>-1</sf:row>
               <sf:column>-1</sf:column>
            </sf:InvalidSObjectFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Same thing against v32.0.

**Response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>sf:INVALID_FIELD</faultcode>
         <faultstring>INVALID_FIELD: 
Select Id,QualifiedApiName,KeyPrefix from EntityDefinition
                           ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:28
No such column 'KeyPrefix' on entity 'EntityDefinition'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:InvalidFieldFault xsi:type="sf:InvalidFieldFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_FIELD</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>Select Id,QualifiedApiName,KeyPrefix from EntityDefinition
                           ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:28
No such column 'KeyPrefix' on entity 'EntityDefinition'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.</sf:exceptionMessage>
               <sf:row>1</sf:row>
               <sf:column>28</sf:column>
            </sf:InvalidFieldFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then it starts working from v33.0 onwards:

**Response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <queryResponse>
         <result>
            <done>true</done>
            <entityTypeName>EntityDefinition</entityTypeName>
            <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
            <records xsi:type="EntityDefinition">
               <Id>4ie1W00001000GkQAI</Id>
               <KeyPrefix>001</KeyPrefix>
               <QualifiedApiName>Account</QualifiedApiName>
            </records>
            <size>1</size>
            <totalSize>1</totalSize>
         </result>
      </queryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Though the Tooling API WSDL said v41.0,  my service endpoint had a different version. Changed to 41.0 and it worked fine. Thank you!